# Htaccess redirect all files from subdirectory in one domain to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I am trying to create a permanent htaccess redirect (301) from all files in one directory in one domain, to another domain as follows:

Redirect all files in the following directory:

```
http://www.primary.com/apples/*
```

To:

```
http://www.secondary.com
```

I am not very experienced with htaccess and was wondering if someone can assist me in creating this redirect?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work in one .htaccess file at `primary.com` root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.primary\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^apples/(.*)  http://www.secondary.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Seems to work, just wondering why you are using `(.*)` instead of `(.*)$`.

Comment: In this particular case there is no need for that anchor, although it could be added. Makes no difference. Htaccess regex is based on PCRE so there is no risk of getting stuck in an infinite loop. Check this [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just write in the `http://www.primary.com/apples/` subdirectory `.htaccess` file, and will redirect all your subdirectory to new domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.secondary.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```