# How htaccess rewrite domain to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, redirect

I'm trying to change the name of domain using htaccess , this is i want :
`http://olddomaine.com/subname/*` to `http://newdomaine.com/*`
I'm using this solution , but the page just load without nothing :( :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^olddomaine\.com$

RedirectMatch 301 ^/subname/$ http://newdomaine.com/

#RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomaine.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
#RewriteRule ^subname/(.*)  http://newdomaine.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing mod-rewrite with mod-alias. Both would work for your required redirects, but you should only use a single method.

The following is using `mod-alias`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RedirectPermanent /subname http://newdomain.com/
```

and the following one is using `mod-rewrite`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subname(?:/(.*))$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but this not working for the rest page , for example :http://newdomaine/page.php  i have always  http://olddomaine.com/subname/page.php with 404 not found :'(

Comment: @OumayaAbdelkhalek Can you explain what you mean? I did not understand the comment.

Comment: sorry :( , i want to say that your solution is working fine with the first page http://newdomain.com/ , but when I'm trying to redirect to another page for example http://newdomain.com/page.php , it's not working , i have this url :  http://olddomaine.com/subname/page.php and error 404 not found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864690/htaccess-redirect-all-files-from-subdirectory-in-one-domain-to-another-domain , i have the some problm , but this solution not working :(

Comment: @OumayaAbdelkhalek When you visit `http://olddomaine.com/subname/page.php`, do you get redirected to `http://newdomain.com/page.php` or just `http://newdomain.com/`?

Comment: i have http://newdomaine.com/subname/page.php , and i have an empty page , in console: http://olddomaine.com/subname/subname/subname/subname/subname/subname/subname/subname//page.php :'(((((((

Comment: @OumayaAbdelkhalek Then you have some other rule overriding the one I provided above.

Comment: @OumayaAbdelkhalek You had some other rules previously? Since you are using `R=301` everywhere, maybe the browser has cached your redirects. Another possibility is that the rule for redirection comes from somewhere else?

Comment: see the answer please :)