# Redirecting Urls from old website to New

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect my website from old domain to new domain using htaccess. Both the websites have same pages with same url structure i only need to redirect the main url part i-e https://test.com old url to https://test1.com with other pages url as well. For example if i had a page in old website (https://test.com/page1) it should be redirected to (https://test1.com/page1). I used this code to redirect it but its not working any help.

```
Redirect 301 /page1/ https://test1.com/page1

Redirect 301 https://test1.com
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess redirect all files from subdirectory in one domain to another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864690/htaccess-redirect-all-files-from-subdirectory-in-one-domain-to-another-domain)

Comment: If any of our answers have helped, please upvote or accept any that have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You might find these helpful:

```
#Redirect from old domain to new domain
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
#Redirect from old domain to new domain with full path and query string:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

Feel free to follow the resource: https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489

Answer (score 0):

The first [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) has a different source and target URL-path. The old URL has a trailing slash and new one has not.

> Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

This means, if you request

```
http://old.example.com/page1/some/script.php
```

the path beyond `/page1/` (some/script.php *without* leading slash) will be taken and attached to the target `/page1`

```
http://new.example.com/page1some/script.php
```

To have the complete path appended, you must omit the trailing slash in the old URL-path, e.g.

```
Redirect /page1 https://test1.com/page1
```

---

To address the second [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), this will only work inside a [`Location`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#location) directive, e.g.

```
<Location "/page1">
    Redirect https://test1.com/page1
</Location>
```

---

Finally, when everything works as it should, you may change the status code to `301`. *Never* test with [`301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).